# Implementing a generic method for classes that implements an interface

Tags: java

recently I decided to dive a bit into Java, using it in a personal project, and one of the classes I end up writing a class to pick a random value between a list of weighted values.

First thing I did was write an interface IWeighable, which has only one method:

```
double getWeight();
```

So every class I want to pick with this randomizer has to implement such interface to be able to get the weight value of the option.

Now, here's what I had wrote until recently (trying to improve it right now):

```
public IWeighable getRandomWeighable(List<IWeighable> weighables)
{
    double totalWeight = 0.0;

    for (IWeighable weighable : weighables)
    {
        if (weighable.getWeight() > 0)
            totalWeight += weighable.getWeight();
    }

    double selected = SRandom.randDouble() * totalWeight;

    for (IWeighable weighable : weighables)
    {
        double weight = weighable.getWeight();
        selected -= weight;

        if (selected <= 0)
            return weighable;
    }

    return null;
}
```

But I just realized that this probably is not the best way to code it. Why? Because for instance, if I write a class "Encounter" which implements "IWeighable", I can't simply invoke:

```
List<Encounter> encounters;
...
Encounter rEncounter = WeightedRandomizer.getInstance().getRandomWeighable(encounters);
```

Because "encounters" is not of type `List <IWeighable>`.

I tried changing the signature of "getRandomWeighable" to something like:

```
public IWeighable getRandomWeighable(List<Class<? extends IWeighable>> weighables) {
```

But that would require a lot of generics work, which I'm fine with, but they can throw all sorts of exceptions, which is something I would like to avoid in this particular code. I feel there is an easier and better way to write this, I just am struggling to find it right now.

Any tips?

Kind regards and thanks for the help

**EDIT**

Welp, I just gave it a little more thoughts and tries and solved it by changing the getRandomWeighable signature to:

```
public <T extends IWeighable> T getRandomWeighable(List<T> weighables)
```

I'm thinking about deleting this question, but maybe it is useful to another Java newbie like myself, so, not sure.

Comment: Maybe if you add the *edit* as an answer it might help.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to accept any list with generic type implementing `IWeighable` you can use [Upper Bounded Wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) `List<? extends IWeighable>`:

```
public IWeighable getRandomWeighable(List<? extends IWeighable> weighables) {
  ...
}
```